# required airport transit visa for italy

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, layovers, rome, sudanese-citizens

I'm travelling from UAE to London through Fiumicino airport . Do I need an Anairport transit visa for a 2-hour layover in the Fiumicino airport? I hava a valid visa to Uk

Comment: It partly depends on what passport you hold.

Comment: Sudanese passport .